# How to position agents on Conveyorbelt at initiation?

Tags: anylogic

I am currently trying to initialize a running factory in AnyLogic, but I can't find a feasible solution to my conveyorbelt issue. I can't find a way to position an agent at a certain distance from the exit of a conveyorbelt at initiation.

Is there a way to place the agents at a certain point on the conveyor, any workaround for my problem or is this a hopeless case?

I have tried to create a conveyorbelt network using the material handling library and using the conveyor element, but the moment the agent "enters" the conveyorbelt it just gets beamed to the start of the conveyorbelt and passes through it without any regard to the position I set it to prior.

I have also tried to solve this, by having multiple entry points to the conveyorbelt, but as I am creating a model for a glass bottle factory, which can have up to thousands of bottles on the conveyor at the same time, and they can be just centimeters away from eachother, the solution to move them onto the belt through certain entries isn't feasible either.

I have also began working on my own custom conveyor, but I realize it's very complicated to fully create a conveyor using a queue, a delay and some custom classes...